# "Крепостные стены сохраняли свою цитадель"? Средневековье стен, глубокое?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Два расположенных друг за другом средневековых двора внутри святой
>   обители – **крепостные стены**, которые с момента возведения, ещё до
>   нашей эры, сдались лишь раз – во время пожара, устроенного норманнами
>   в 1084 году, а после **были приведены в порядок и с тех пор сохраняли
>   свою цитадель** (они и теперь удерживают её суровое молчание). **Из их глубокого средневековья тяжело стелется запах лака** по уходу за старым-старым деревом и древняя сырость.

А?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Два расположенных друг за другом средневековых двора внутри святой обители.** Их крепостные стены с момента возведения, ещё до нашей эры, сдались лишь раз – во время пожара, устроенного норманнами в 1084 году, **но потом**  были приведены в порядок и с тех пор сохраняли свою цитадель (они и теперь удерживают её суровое молчание). Из их глубокого средневековья тяжело стелется запах лака по уходу за старым-старым деревом и древняя сырость.

Пояснение

1) Все "сомнительные" значения переносные и **вполне приемлемые**.

2) Начало текста не очень ясное, лучше использовать **именительный темы.** Первое предложение содержит **два тире**, структура предложения понимается не сразу.

3) С цитаделью вроде бы понятно:

Цитаде́ль (итал. cittadella — небольшой городок) — крепость, защищающая город, либо **внутреннее укрепление крепости,** имевшее самостоятельную оборону, являвшееся общим редюитом крепости и служившее **последним опорным пунктом** для гарнизона крепости в случае падения основных её укреплений.

4) Два раза встречаются слова ***средневековых, средневековья.*** Это немного напрягает слух,  но заменить их сложно.